# HDF5: How to read tightly packed array of vertices into a struct of different size?

Tags: c++, hdf5, data-conversion

I have the following format stored in an HDF5 file (tightly packed array of vertices):

```
struct DiskVertex
{
    float pos[3];
}
```

And I have a memory buffer of vertices I want to read this data into:

```
struct MemVertex
{
    float pos[3];
    float normal[3];
    float uv[2];
}
```

For example, if there were DiskVertex[1000] on disk, and a memory buffer of MemVertex[1000].

How can I read the data from DiskVertex into MemVertex?  I want to avoid allocating a temporary buffer, reading the array into it, then copying that data into the destination.

Comment: Not sure about this, but hdf5 allows you to specify different datatypes for that data stored in the file and data stored in memory, this can be used to e.g change/normalize the endianess on the fly. You should read up the section about custom datatypes in the hdf5 manual

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!  I find the docs difficult to follow, to be honest.

Comment: Please read section `7.4. Dataspaces and Data Transfer` of the reference manual found here http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/HDF5-1.8.7/UG/12_Dataspaces.html (I know, it's old but still valid even for newer versions of the HDF5 library). Basically, you need to specify a memory dataspace (or layout) that "tells" to HDF5 where/how to transfer the data read from disk into memory.

Comment: FYI: float[] members (variable length arrays) are not standard C++.

Comment: float[] not standard?  C'mon man!  I meant to put float pos[3].  I'll fix it.